# Can't run db2 Query?

Tags: c#, db2

I get the following error:

**SQL0104 Token GCOMN was not valid. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT ORDER UNION EXCEPT OFFSET.**

This is the parameterized query I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN GCOMN = 82 THEN 'S040'
    WHEN GCOMN = 2 THEN 'S041'
    END as SalesOrgId,
    gcusn as BillToId,
    gshpn as ShipTo_Mapics,
    sapcusn as ShipTo_SAP
FROM YSHPEXT WHERE GCOMN= ?GCOMN AND GCUSN= ?GCUSN AND GSHPN= ?GSHPN
```

I know for a fact that "GCOMN" is a valid column name.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a typo - such strange expressions like `?COLUMN`.
Try to prepare the following and bind the parameters appropriately.:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN GCOMN = 82 THEN 'S040'
    WHEN GCOMN = 2 THEN 'S041'
    END as SalesOrgId,
    gcusn as BillToId,
    gshpn as ShipTo_Mapics,
    sapcusn as ShipTo_SAP
FROM YSHPEXT 
WHERE GCOMN=? AND GCUSN=? AND GSHPN=?;
```

Comment: You may try `:column` as well, if you want to use named parameters. But you must set the [EnableNamedParameterSupport](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0055319.html) variable explicitly in your db2cli.ini conf file.

Comment: thanks, that was it. EHH! error message is horrible!